# Writing a nonrecursive formula

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there an easy way to figure out nonrecursive formulas? My problem is:
Suppose a sequence is defined by
$A_0=1$
$A_n=nA_{n-1}$ for $n\le2$

I found that $A_2=2$, $A_3=6$, $A_4=24$, $A_5=120$

I know I'll probably have an exam question with finding non recursive formulas so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way is to know (or conjecture) the nonrecursive formula, and then proving it by induction. Do you have an idea of what could be the result ?

Comment: The easiest way is to look it up in the OEIS: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C6%2C24%2C120&sort=&language=&go=Search

Comment: @KevinQuirin Don't I need to know the non recursive formula before I prove it by strong induction?

Comment: @ematth7 No. It is enough to "suspect" it. The proof by induction is the confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is, $a_{n}=n!=n(n-1)....1$ and $a_0=0!=1$.

Because $a_n=n!=n(n-1)!=na_{n-1}$

Comment: Arguably, $n!$ is itself (defined as) a recursive formula.

Comment: @drhab I edit it, hope it be ok, now :)